# Children div 100% height from parent

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs and one ul with content inside, the ul height is not always the same, sometimes will have 100% or more of the parent and other less, how can i do to make padding bottom when the height is more than 100%?

HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">
        <ul>
            <li>Test</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#parent {
    max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
    background-color: red;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#child {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Here an example in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag5nasvj/4/)

Im trying to use jScrollPane inside the ul too but

Thank you!

Comment: what is not working exactly?

Comment: the padding-bottom in the parent or child div

Comment: everything is displayed fine on my pc...the padding is working properly..
try to remove the height if you want to use the padding for spacing

Comment: make the window small

Comment: Try `overflow: scroll;` for #parent

Comment: why? i will use jscrollpane to the ul content, i only want to watch the padding-bottom inside #parent

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `overflow: hidden` to `body` too.

```
body {overflow: hidden}
```

Comment: Don't understand why but doesn't work [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ag5nasvj/5/)

Answer (score 0):

Did some css hack to get this. Added 10px of border-bottom with the same container color and a box-shadow for black border-bottom.

```
#parent {
    max-height: calc(100% - 50px);
    background-color: red;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 black;
    border-bottom: 10px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/ag5nasvj/7/)

Hope this helps!